# trigger colorbox on view page load

Tags: views, javascript

What if I just want to trigger the first colorbox on a view page? maybe with js injector module.

```
  Drupal.behaviors.commerce_kickstart_theme_custom_mytest = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $('.view-promoted-to-front-2 .views-row-1 > .views-field-rendered-entity .node-product-display .field-group-colorbox-trigger').trigger('click');  
         });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not use the js injector module. Colorbox integrates seamlessly well with views. If you are displaying content as fields in the view (which I think you are) you can use the :

Fields -> Add

option to introduce a colorbox trigger.

[image]

For example, Lets consider the below fields :

[image]

The first item "Content : Gallery Image Upload"  has the following settings

[image]

The second item "Content : Gallery Image Upload"  has the following settings

[image]

and you set up your colorbox trigger like below :

[image]

The replacement pattern is all that matters here. If you are
confused what to put for **popup**, scroll all the way down
to Replacement Patterns and select appropriate field and paste
it in the **popup** box. Here the trigger field is the the first
"Content : Gallery Image Upload" field and when somebody clicks
it we are introducing a colorbox trigger to start the colorbox
slideshow configured for the second "Content : Gallery Image Upload"
field.

In short, we are setting up a Gallery here. :)